# What's the psychological issue name of fear of people?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, psychology, diagnosis

With the issue of being afraid of doing anything before people, one has to work hard on self control to prevent the body shaking on every tiny action, like hold a pen, drink water, etc, and when there's many people looking at him/her, it becomes almost impossible to hold shaking, to speak normally, or to think. This person is subconsciously in fear of people unhappy(?) with his actions, even though he knows there's nothing wrong with his behavior.

Is this a typical case in Psychology? Is there a name for it?

### Scenario for some background information

his mother died when he was very young, his father don't like him, never talked to him except call everyone dinner, never smiled to him, never spent time with him, never gave any recognition even he got full marks, curse and beat him on whatever excuse when not in good mood.

He lived in a room with a big window in the wall next to the living room(a request for curtain was rejected), he had no idea why father dissatisfied with him (he's always one of the best in his class during student period and never asked for anything from his father, if exclude care), but been used to keep an ear out on his father all the time when at home, for whenever his father step into the living room where he would be seen through the window, he could sit as straight as he can before his desk and try not to move a bit, he didn't want to give him any excuse to curse, to beat.

Comment: Hi Edward, welcome to CogSci. I'm afraid self-help questions are off-topic here. If you could generalize your question,and remove any reference to self, that would be great. I'm having difficulty with advising on how, but perhaps you could talk about fear of people, fear of failing and ask whether childhood may be involved or something. Without substantial edits we have to put this question on hold. In short - seek professional care instead of relying on anonymous folks behind their keyboard.

Comment: @AliceD thanks, I have edit my question, what I want to do is listing the symptoms, and if it is a know issue in psychology (I believe so), hopefully someone will tell us the issue name. Psychology is a joke in my country, so I really have no choice.

Comment: There can be no difinitive answer to this question as it stands unfortunatley as it can lead to a broad range of diagnoses. Rather than a fear of people, it sounds like you could be talking about a [fear of rejection](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/intimacy-path-toward-spirituality/201404/deconstructing-the-fear-rejection).  It would be difficult to judge based on such a short description of problems and so I could be wrong.  (Cont...)

Comment: (Cont...) It could also be a symptom of many different psycholgical problems including anxiety.  Someone coming to me discussing this problem would lead me to try and explore this with the person a bit more to form a more solid idea of the real issue.

Comment: @Chris, I have added back the lacked background information of the persion that necessary for determine the category or name of the issue. I had to modify it to meet the criteria here.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if there is a name for subconscious, irrational fear of people being unhappy with one's actions?

Answer (score 4):

The general symptoms (NOT the background scenario) may point to a psychological disorter called  social phobia :

> [Social anxiety disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_anxiety_disorder) (SAD), also known as **social phobia**, is an
> anxiety disorder characterized by a significant amount of fear in one
> or more social situations, causing considerable distress and impaired
> ability to function in at least some parts of daily life.
>
> ...
>
> **Physical symptoms** often include excessive blushing, excess sweating, trembling, palpitations, and nausea. Stammering may be present, along with rapid speech.
>
> ...
>
> The first line **treatment** for social anxiety disorder is cognitive
> behavioral therapy (CBT) ... . The cognitive and behavioral components
> seek  to change thought patterns and physical reactions to
> anxiety-inducing
> situations. ... . Prescribed medications include several
> classes of antidepressants: selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors
> (SSRIs), serotonin-norepinephrine reuptake inhibitors (SNRIs), and
> monoamine oxidase inhibitors (MAOIs)
>
> ...
>
> It is the most common anxiety disorder with up to 10% of people being affected at some point in their life